# How to configure mondrian olap to use ehcache for perforamnce boost

Tags: mondrian

I want to configure Mondrian OLAP to use EhCache. Has anyone tried to do this, please share your thoughts and how to do on the same.

Answer (score 2):

You should take a look at Mondrian's [SegmentCache SPI](http://mondrian.pentaho.com/api/mondrian/spi/SegmentCache.html). It allows you to implement custom cache providers for cell data. There is an [example available](https://github.com/pentaho/mondrian/blob/lagunitas/src/main/mondrian/rolap/cache/MemorySegmentCache.java) in the default in-memory implementation.

Answer (score 2):

Also take a look at one of the CTools - CDC - Community Distributed Cache - lets you control the cache and so on..

http://forums.pentaho.com/showthread.php?95994-CDC-Community-Distributed-Cache